# Duplicate mongodb objects params but only one gets shown? Last digits get rounded?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js, steam

So I am experiencing a number of oddities with my db. It started when I noticed after I logged in that my balance was not what it used to be. Then I found two apparently different accounts that have the same number. Anyways. I am working with passport and the strategy is steam. Here is a look at my two issues in coding form:

First oddity:
*When using steam as the strategy I get back a user with a steam id.

```
{ steamid: '76561198053118469',
  communityvisibilitystate: 3,
  profilestate: 1,
  personaname: 'What Comes Around™',
  commentpermission: 1,
  profileurl: 'https://steamcommunity.com/id/WCAOfficial/',
  avatar:
   'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/99/99f12061912d535322c9a23ee7d17ce341c27c56.jpg',
  avatarmedium:
   'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/99/99f12061912d535322c9a23ee7d17ce341c27c56_medium.jpg',
  avatarfull:
   'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/99/99f12061912d535322c9a23ee7d17ce341c27c56_full.jpg',
  lastlogoff: 1587637203,
  personastate: 1,
  primaryclanid: '103582791466140922',
  timecreated: 1321956195,
  personastateflags: 0 }
```

This is the returned req.user. As you can see the user.steamid is: 76561198053118469

Here is my current users collection in my db:

```
[ { balance: 100,
    _id: 5e9a43519eabc40017ed6a85,
    userid: 76561198053118460,
    profileurl: 'https://steamcommunity.com/id/WCAOfficial/',
    __v: 0 },
  { balance: 0,
    _id: 5ea22ae86407a43c389210bd,
    userid: 76561198053118460,
    profileurl: 'https://steamcommunity.com/id/WCAOfficial/',
    __v: 0 } ]
```

So the first thing I don't understand is why the steam id has had it's last digit rounded. Now I didn't include an actual user in here, but one of my users has an id ending with something like 69, and that gets rounded to 80 for some reason. I cannot for the life of my understand this.

Next issue, ok so forget about the first issue. Fine, somewhere down the line the values get rounded or something. FINE. So if I use find( {userid: 76561198053118460}) I should get back both users with the two different balances, right? Well no, I don't get that back. Instead I get back the one that I get logged into, the one with 0 balance. This. This boggles my mind honestly. How this is possible doesn't make sense to me.

So there are my two issues. I'd like to end this question with a disclaimer. I have played around with mongoose for some time now I'd consider myself a beginner. So I really hope it's a problem with an answer is that real obvious but if it is, sorry for the noob question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open your favorite browser's console and type `76561198053118469` in there, you are going to get back `76561198053118460`. This is because `76561198053118469` is interpreted [as a floating-point number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates) (in javascript) and thus is stored inexactly.

Make sure everywhere you are operating on user ids you are using strings and are storing the ids as strings, not numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much. Looks like this was a noob question XD, but hey, we all start somewhere. Will remember this mistake for sure :).